# Convert datetime string to timestamp

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to convert string with this value to timestamp: 4/12/2023 3:03:10 AM

This doesnt work:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('4/12/2023 3:03:10 AM') AS timestamp
```

Returns error: SQL Error [100035] [22007]: Timestamp '4/12/2023 3:03:10 AM' is not recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing explicitly format:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('4/12/2023 3:03:10 AM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') AS timestamp
-- 2023-12-04 03:03:10.000
```